# NameError Using Custom Model Manager

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to add a custom model manager to a class that's sub-classing    `AbstractBaseUser` in a model and I get:

```
NameError `NameError: name 'AccountManager' is not defined.
```

I've looked at example code basically the same as mine, I've read the docs, and googled it to no avail. I simply don't understand why it won't work. Here in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/) is an example of sub-classing the `AbstractBaseUser` and using a custom model manager, so obviously it should work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The Code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: where is your `AccountManager` class defined ? If you dont have one, just comment that line out.

Comment: Well that's extremely embarrassing, I had forgotten to paste it in, lol. Going on no sleep for 2 days will do that I suppose. . .Thank you, and my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I had simply forgotten to paste the AccountManager back into my code. Lack of sleep can cause some moronic mistakes (and questions). My apologies. Thanks to Karthikr for pointing this out!